# Comando ls en Git Bash en Windows

Tags: git, git-bash

Tengo una duda sobre los resultados de color azul celeste del comando 'ls' que aparecen en la consola de Git Bash en Windows.
Por ejemplo, en mi carpeta de usuario aparecen **'Mis documentos' @** y unos cuantos más. ¿Son enlaces simbólicos o variables de entorno?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Acabo de ver que son carpetas especiales de Windows. ¿Alguien sabe si hay diferencia entre esto y los enlaces simbólicos?

Comment: Las variables de entorno no se ven con un `ls`.